# Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this error showing me up, all the time I run my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import glob
import scipy


pe_day = []
day = []
f = open("PE0.txt", "r").readlines()
for each_day in f:
    (day, pe) = each_day.split()
    day = str(day)
    pe_day.append(float(pe))
    print(pe_day)
    print(day[14:16])
    plt.plot(pe_day, float(day), '-',  color = 'g')    
f.close()
plt.show()
```

As I have been working with python 3.3 and I am a new programmer, I don't have any clue where I should start.

Comment: what does `day` contain? May be it contains some non-numeric values

Comment: Put `print(day, pe)` after the line containing `(day, pe) = each_day.split()` and see what it prints out...

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, you have non-numeric chars in the second field. To circumvent this type of exceptions, use similar code as below:

```
    try:
        pe_day.append(float(pe))
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error occured while  trying to convert pe value: %s to float " % (pe)
        print "Errors :\n\t\t", sys.exc_info()[0], ":\t", e
```